# Which movie is about human-eating gremlins?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a movie about small creatures, possibly gremlins of some sort.

I can only remember the last scene before the credits when the protagonist (a boy) thought he was safe and everything was alright. Then:

> He went into the kitchen and saw green slime and stuff. He looked at the table and he saw the creatures/gremlins eating a person and one of the creatures looked at him and said: "Your momma tastes good, Boy."

Comment: Why would a human eat gremlins?!?!? *Because you forgot to use a hyphen.* Grammar: It Saves (Gremlin) Lives™.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Best Grammar Comment of the Year awarded!

Comment: @Anton: Not to be pedantic (perish the thought), but I’m a [*zombie* grammar Nazi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Snow).

Comment: @jv42: there really should be a badge for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging by the quote this would be [Troll 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105643/), an incredibly stupid B-Movie (that despite its title does not feature any trolls and is in no way a sequel to "Troll").

Here's [an essay](http://www.salon.com/2010/05/14/best_worst_movie/) about Troll 2. See if sounds familiar.